# Very small resolution on external monitor Windows 7 with Macbook Pro Retina

Tags: macbook-pro, windows, parallels-desktop, resolution

I have a Macbook Pro Retina 13", and I run both OSX and Windows 7. My Windows 7 is run in Parallels.

I work with OSX on the screen of the Macbook, and Windows on an external monitor (with the typical 1900x1080 resolution).

Problem is the Windows screen has very bad dimensions. Some things are very small, others are normal size. Screenshot:

[image]

When I go into my screen resolution it says 3840x2160, which seems very high. However, when I go lower, for instance to 1920x1080, I get the following which looks totally bad on my monitor (extremely big icons / other things):

Any idea how to get a normal resolution of my Windows screen?

[image]

Comment: Click on `Make text and other items larger or smaller`

Comment: Changing the DPI does nothing. It goes back to 199% when I click "Log off", unfortunately

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I got it fixed, by selecting "Scaled" in the options in Parallels. Then I could change the screen resolution, and I had no problems in Windows 7. Success!

[image]